# WinRT - How to use custom control from another project within the same solution?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, custom-controls

I use Visual Studio 2015 and create a WinRT Universal App.

For my custom controls I have created a project within the same solution. Now I need to use the controls in the main application project, but they don't appear in the designer Toolbox. The Toolbox displays only controls from the active project, but not the controls from the whole solution. Is there a way to use my custom controls in the main project? I tried Add Reference for my auxiliary project in Solution Explorer, but it didn't help.

Comment: Maybe just add namespace to your xaml page and write it by hand?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for toolbox to display your custom control from all your project inside the solution. You need to define the namespace in xaml and write the code manually.